# ¿Cómo actualizar los registros?

Tags: php, html, mysql, table

Tengon un problema, espero puedan apoyarme, tengo una table, en el cual muestro los archivos que se subieron, lo que quiero hacer es aprobar y rechazar mediante un select box, el problema es que a la hora de actualizar solo me lo hace con el último registro, quisiera saber que tengo que hacer para que el select se haga 1 por 1.

```
        $queryE = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT ar.id_archivos, ar.name, em.nombreE, es.estatus, 
        ar.ruta from t_archivos ar 
        join t_empresas em on em.idt_empresas = ar.id_empresa join t_estatus es on es.idt_estatus = 
        ar.id_estatus ORDER BY ar.id_archivos
       ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina ");
        
        $resultE = mysqli_num_rows($queryE);
        if($resultE > 0){
              while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($queryE)) {

        ?>          
        <tr>

                    <td style="display:none;"><input name="id_archivos" class="id" required value="<?php echo $data["id_archivos"]; ?>" /></td>
                          
                    <td name="name" ><?php  echo $data["name"]; ?></td>
                    
                     <td name="nombreE"><?php  echo $data["nombreE"]; ?></td>

                     
                       <td><a target="_blank" href="larchivos.php?id=<?php echo $data['id_archivos']?>"><?php echo $data['ruta']; ?></a></td>

                     <td name="nombreE"><?php  echo $data["estatus"]; ?></td>
                     
                    <td><label for="id_estatus"></label>
      <?php
      $query_estatus = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM t_estatus");
     
      $result_estatus = mysqli_num_rows($query_estatus);
      ?>
      <select name="id_estatus" id="id_estatus" >
        <?php
        if($result_estatus > 0){
           while ($id_estatus = mysqli_fetch_array($query_estatus)){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $id_estatus["idt_estatus"]; ?>"><?php echo $id_estatus["estatus"] 
           ?></option>
          <?php
          
        
          }
          }
          ?>

                          </select>
```

Este es mi update, lo he checado por separado y si me lo hace

```
         $sql_update = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE t_archivos SET id_estatus = '$id_estatus' 
          WHERE id_archivos='$id_archivos'");
        
              if ($sql_update) {
                    $alert='<p class="msg_save">Gracias por tu acción.</p>';
              }else{
                    $alert='<p class="msg_error">Acción no realizada.</p>';
              }
```

Comment: Trata de indentar mejor tu código, es más facil de leer.

Comment: Hola. Dime si entendí bien: ¿Necesitas poder marcar varias opciones simultáneamente en el select? Si es así necesitas establecer el atributo **multiple** del elemento. Lee [the select element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element) Mientras no esté establecido, **es tu caso** la selección se hará uno a uno.

Comment: Si son varios registros y todos los _select_ tienen el mismo nombre `name="id_estatus"`, el navegador enviará solo 1. Necesitas manejarlos como arreglo: `name="id_estatus[]"`, lo mismo para _id_archivo_. En PHP vas a necesitar un ciclo para crear las consultas.